# Node.js - How to get relative require paths?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a module that works like so:

*/helpers/importer/Import.js*

```
function importer(requiredModulePath, toImport) {
  requiredModulePath = requiredModulePath.replace('{env}', browser.params.env);
  var requiredModule = require(requiredModulePath);

  return requiredModule[toImport] || requiredModule.default || requiredModule;
}

module.exports = importer;
```

I use this to import module properties dynamically, such as the following "URLs" module:

*/example/URLs.js*

```
module.exports = {
  default: 'http://google.com',
  a: 'http://a.com',
  b: 'http://c.com'
};
```

And I do this like so:

*/example/myExecutingModule.js*

```
var Import = require('../helpers/importer/Import');
//var URL = Import('./URLs');             //This path does not work
var URL = Import('../../example/URLs');   //This path does work, as the URL is relative to Import.js 
[ ... ]
```

My problem here is that, unlike everyone else on stack overflow, who wants absolute paths in their requires, I want the opposite. I would like to supply the same path to my Import function that I would supply to require -- the one that is relative to myExecutingModule.js, in this case: './URLs'. However, it seems like my "importer" function has closure over the "require" function which is relative to its path. Is there any way to write it such that "require" will be relative to the module calling importer()? As I type this, it feels like the only way would be to pass "require" into the Import.js module, which I feel is kind of... ridiculous

EDIT: After thinking on this further I am guessing that the answer involves giving Import closure over the calling module's require function, like so:

```
var Import = require('../helpers/Import')(require);
```

And then the export in Import.js will be

```
module.exports = function (require) { [...] return importer; };
```

Causing "require" within the importer function to be the actual require function that the calling module would have used. I have not tried this yet, and I'm holding out for a better answer, so I will leave this question open for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I am using now. Passing "require" to the Import module from the calling module, so that it is importing relative to the calling module's location.

```
var import = require('../helpers/Import')(require);
var URL = import('./URLs');
```

And then Import.js uses the calling module's require instead of its own:

```
module.exports = function (require) {
  function importer(requiredModulePath) {

    [ ... ]

    var requiredModule = require(requiredModulePath);
    return requiredModule[toImport] || requiredModule.default || requiredModule;
  }

  return importer;
};
```

Feels a little weird but, what can ya do

Answer (score 1):

You can use `__dirname` which is set to the directory that the current module is in. For example: `__dirname + '/URLs'`

Comment: Yes, I considered something like this, But this doesn't allow my paths passed to "Import.js" to be the same as those passed to "require(str)" -- ie.  I specifically want to write Import.js in a way that passing "./URLs.js" works in this example. One of the reasons I want this is so that my IDE can tell where the files are in my system. Another is so that the path is interchangeable whether I am using require() or my Import() module

Answer (score 1):

Try the [local-modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-modules) package.  I've used it in production on node 0.10 and io.js 2.3 so far without any problems.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-modules

https://github.com/intesso/local-modules

Comment: I think this is actually the opposite of what I want?